# Access GA API with Django: /accounts/login/ redirect issue

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-api-python-client, oauth2client

I'm working on Django app that will provide to users the information about their Google Analytics accounts (Account ID, Property, View ID).

But I'm stacked on the very beginning trying to resolve the problem with authorization of the user (handling oAuth 2 server response).

I followed the Google documentation on it.

MODELS.PY

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from oauth2client.django_orm import FlowField, CredentialsField


class FlowModel(models.Model):
    id = models.ForeignKey(User, primary_key=True)
    flow = FlowField()


class CredentialsModel(models.Model):
    id = models.ForeignKey(User, primary_key=True)
    credential = CredentialsField()
```

VIEWS.PY

```
import os
import httplib2
from oauth2client import xsrfutil
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.django_orm import Storage

from apiclient.discovery import build

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.sites.models import get_current_site

from .models import CredentialsModel, FlowModel

CLIENT_SECRETS = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'client_secrets.json')


def get_accounts_ids(service):
    accounts = service.management().accounts().list().execute()
    ids = []
    if accounts.get('items'):
        for account in accounts['items']:
            ids.append(account['id'])
    return ids


@login_required
def index(request):
    # use the first REDIRECT_URI if you are developing your app
    # locally, and the second in production
    REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/oauth2callback'
    #REDIRECT_URI = "https://%s%s" % (
    #     get_current_site(request).domain, reverse("oauth2:return"))
    FLOW = flow_from_clientsecrets(
        CLIENT_SECRETS,
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
        redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI
    )
    user = request.user
    storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', user, 'credential')
    credential = storage.get()
    if credential is None or credential.invalid is True:
        FLOW.params['state'] = xsrfutil.generate_token(
            settings.SECRET_KEY, user)
        authorize_url = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()
        webbrowser.open_new(authorize_url)
        f = FlowModel(id=user, flow=FLOW)
        f.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(authorize_url)
    else:
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credential.authorize(http)
        service = build('analytics', 'v3', http=http)
        ids = get_account_ids(service)
        return render(
            request, 'ga_auth2/main.html', {'ids':ids})


@login_required
def auth_return(request):
    user = request.user
    if not xsrfutil.validate_token(
            settings.SECRET_KEY, request.REQUEST['state'], user):
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
    FLOW = FlowModel.objects.get(id=user).flow
    credential = FLOW.step2_exchange(request.REQUEST)
    storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', user, 'credential')
    storage.put(credential)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/oauth2")
```

URLS.PY

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'oauth2callback', views.auth_return, name='return'),
]
```

The problem is that when I go to http://localhost:8080/oauth2
it's being redirected to http://localhost:8080/accounts/login/?next=/oauth2/
and I see 404 error Page not found.

I defined the API project in Google Developpers Console:
Javascript origins: localhost:8080

Redirect uri: localhost:8080/oauth2/oauth2callback

I imagine the with this redirect I'm pushed to login in my Google account. 
But when I execute my Python code from prompt, the browser is being opened automatically asking me login and/or authorize the API access.

How could I handle this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You've protected your index view with `login_required`, so it's going to redirect you to the login page. If you don't want that, don't use that decorator.